# Julius Warning: strip: sample 0-255 is invalid, stripped

Tags: c++, linux

Julius was working perfectly fine till the other day and suddenly i get this warning today:

**Warning: strip: sample 0-255 is invalid, stripped**

I am using the julius lib api and i get this warning in the program and also while using the julius standalone program.It was working perfectly and now i get this warning!!! Cry

I was using pulseaudio as the -input parameter.I made no changes to any audio settings.Also i can record using Audacity so the mic is working perfectly fine.

Platform: xubuntu 12.04
AUDIO: USB mic

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable explanation of that error message here:

http://julius.sourceforge.jp/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1738

I was experiencing this same behavior in the julius standalaone program.  ( Same setup, xubuntu 12.04, USB audio ).  Part of my problem was that julius as distributed by xubuntu tries to use the oss audio system, while xubuntu is using pulseaudio.

- One solution is to run julius in the wrapper program 'padsp'
- The better solution is to compile julius yourself for pulseaudio.

Once I did that (and un-muted the mic) I no longer get the warning.